# Accessing PHP output buffer contents using python

Tags: php, python, html

Is it Possible to access or retrieve the data from PHP output buffer using python, In my case i have an png image in php variable,

if i pass the php variable to image.open($image) will it work?

Comment: Try it and find out.

Comment: did try it but i couldn't get anything ? my question is if it is possible to do such thing @MattDMo

Comment: I think what @MattDMo is talking about is that you should tell us what you've tried, post the most concise version of your code that isn't working, and tell us what isn't working.  Questions that start with "Is it possible" are a red flag.

Answer (score 0):

No.

To exchange data between PHP and Python (or any other two languages), use a file, a socket or shared memory (or stdin/stdout through pipes).